# Project-Tango | Unity Meshing crashes app

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I downloaded the new Jih build of the [Project-Tango Unity Samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity).

Setting up my new project, I made sure to set the minimum API level to 17 in the Player Settings.

Howevery, when I try to start any of the two Meshing Demo scenes the App instantly crashes.

[This](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bakedCouchPotato/48b1ef6064160f39aa6f/raw/5d80f1178e10c94791c7f5ffb1d2704963215f48/logcat.txt) is what I got from logcat, but I can't make any sense of it.

How do I fix this? Allowing out of date API did not help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug with Unity on Tango. Try turn off the `dynamic batching` in `player settings`